# Gradle custom compilation

Tags: maven, gradle, compilation, mapstruct

I want to achieve the following which i did with maven in gradle:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <executions>
            <!-- 1. Exclude Default Compiler -->
            <execution>
                <id>default-compile</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
            <!-- 2. Compile without Mappers. -->
            <execution>
                <id>Compile without Mappers</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/**/mapper/**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <!-- 3. Compile Mappers -->
                <id>Compile Mappers</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/**/mapper/**/*</include>
                        <include>${project.build.directory}/classes/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

What i'm doing is disabling the default compilation, compiling all source files except my Mapstruct mappers and then compiling the Mapstruct mappers including the compiled source from before. I am new to gradle and don't know how i can achieve something similar. What i have tried so far is the following:

```
task compileWithoutMapperClasses(type: JavaCompile) {
    options.incremental = true
    // Compile without Mappers
    sourceSets.main.java.exclude '**/**/mapper/**/*'
}


task compileMapperClasses(type: JavaCompile) {
    sourceSets.main.java.include '**/**/mapper/**/*'
    sourceSets.main.java.include 'build/classes/**/*'

    options.define(
        compilerArgs: [
            "-nowarn",
            "-proc:only",
            "-encoding", "UTF-8",
            "-processor", "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
        ]
    );
}

compileMapperClasses.dependsOn compileWithoutMapperClasses
compileJava.dependsOn compileWithoutMapperClasses
```

The result is actually that nothing gets compiled. The reason why i want to do this is that i want to use lombok and mapstruct within my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
task compileMapperClasses(type: JavaCompile) {
    includes '**/**/mapper/**/*'
    includes 'build/classes/**/*'

    options.define(
        compilerArgs: [
            "-nowarn",
            "-proc:only",
            "-encoding", "UTF-8",
            "-processor", "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
        ]
    );
}
```

For more info, follow confiugration of JavaCompile task https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html

Comment: If you use MapStruct 1.2.0.Beta1 and Lombok 1.16.14, it should work with a single compilation. Our two teams have worked together to make sure that MapStruct can "see" the AST amendments done by Lombok.

Comment: Is there an example how this can be achieved with gradle? Using the mentioned version does not fix my problem.

Comment: There is an example in the [mapstruct-examples](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-lombok) repository.  This works with the version @Gunnar wrote in his comment

Comment: @Martin I am defining a custom Annotation processor within my  gradle plugin. the plugin should define a `JavaCompile` task for each module and pass `-processor` as an apt.  when i define `-processor MyProcessor::class.java.canonicalName` i get this problem `Annotation processor 'com.shaddowface.shuttle.plugin.processors.ShuttleProcessor' not found` any idea why?